# Compact set contained in a union of compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Does anyone know if the following property is true?

Let $A$ an open set contained in $\mathbb{R}^N$, and $\{K_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ a collection of compact sets satisfying $\bigcup_nK_n=A$ and $(K_n) \subseteq\textrm{int}  K_{n+1},\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$.

If $K\subset A$ is a compact, then there exists $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $K\subset K_{m}.$

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $K_n \subset int(K_{n+1})$?

Comment: No, my hypothesis is $int(K_n)\subset K_{n+1}. Is it not true if we suppose this?

Comment: @prosep No. See my comment below Hagen's answer.

Answer (score 6):

Let $A=\Bbb R^N$, $K_n=\{\,x\in\Bbb R^N:\frac 1n\le |x|\le n\,\}\cup\{0\}$, $K=\{\,x\in\Bbb R^N: |x|\le 1\,\}$.

Comment: Ok, I see. And is the property true if we suppose the hypothesis which @Paul Frost suggested?. I edit the post

Comment: The statement is true with the new hypothesis, since $\operatorname{int}(K_n)$ becomes an open cover of $A$ and hence $K$.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Nope. Hagen's example is also a counterexample to this. In the example, $\operatorname{int}(K_n)$ is *not* a cover of $A$ because zero is missing.

Comment: @amsmath We're talking about the case $K_n \subset \operatorname{int}(K_{n+1})$. The counterexample doesn't apply, does it?

Comment: @AymanHourieh Yes, it does. Obviously.

Comment: If $0 \not \in \operatorname{int}(K_{n+1})$ as you say, then how can $K_n$ be contained in it?

Comment: In response to your A, the proposer has added a subsidiary Q, for which I have posted an A.

Comment: @amsmath Have a look at Daniel's answer below. Please check your math in the future and avoid making condescending comments containing "nope" and "obviously" in the future.

Comment: @AymanHourieh I will write whatever I want. But here you were right. Obviously. ;-) However, in the example $\operatorname{int}(K_n)$ is not an open cover of $A = \mathbb R^N$ (as you claimed). So, I guess both of us should check our math.

Answer (score 1):

After the edit of the Q. If $K_n\subset int(K_{n+1})$ then, rather obviously, $A=\cup_n\,K_n\subset \cup_n \, int(K_{n+1})\subset \cup_n\,K_{n+1}\subset \cup_n\,K_n=A,$ so $A=\cup_n \,int(K_{n+1}).$

If $K\subset A$ and $K$ is compact then, since $\{int(K_{n+1}):n\in \Bbb N\}$ is an open cover of $K,$ there is an $n$ such that $\{int(K_{j+1}):j\le n\}$ covers $K.$

By an obvious induction argument, $1\le j<n\implies int(K_{j+1})\subset K_{j+1}\subset int(K_{n+1}).$

So $K\subset \cup_{j=1}^n \,int(K_{j+1})=int(K_{n+1})\subset K_{n+1}.$

Comment: This applies in any topological space, and the condition $K_n\subset int(K_{n+1})$ makes the compactness of $K_n$ irrelevant.